# How to stop views from slicing ISO:8601 date time attributes in rewrite results of a field?

Tags: views, 8, theming

In a Barrio BS4 subtheme I am working on I included the most recent release of  [Timeago.js](http://timeago.yarp.com) as a library, since the ago formatter still seems broken for multilingual.

So, in a couple of views I am making use of the HTML5 time tag. Basically, this:

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</time>
```

Actually, more like this:

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="{{ Created }}">{{ Created_1 }}</time>
```

The previous version of Timeago(1.5.something)made use of UNIX time stamps, and I have that functioning fine in some older BS3 subthemes. However, when trying to include the twigged 'authored on' date as an ISO:8601, the resulting attribute is trimmed to only the digits after the last colon.

Why is that happening? I'd like to know.

Comment: If you are having problems with the multilingual timeago formatters, can you file an issue, too.  Thanks.

Comment: And, you are likely seeing this bug, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2544110

Comment: Probably, thanks. For the Timeago formatter there is this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2639382